# What was Moshe's original name?

Tags: names, moshe-rabbeinu

Did Moshe's parents ever give him a name? If so, what was it?

We know him as Moshe, but that is the name that Pharaoh's daughter gave him.

Presumably, over the several months that Moshe was with his parents, they needed to refer to him somehow.